# Create android gallery view in java file

Tags: android, android-gallery, galleryview

I am comfortable with creating the gallery in the xml and then using it in the java file. However, I am trying to create a new gallery view in the java file. Reasoning is I am not sure at launch how many gallery views I would need and would like to be able to dynamically create gallery view as needed.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LayoutInflater` to get a view from your xml and create as many new instances of it as you want based on whatever your business logic is. I'm not sure I understand when/why it would make sense to do this though...

To use a `LayoutInflater`, do something like this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.somelayout,
                null);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I have some images in separate albums online, i want to show these in gallery views (one for each album) and I do not always know the number of albums. After I inflate the layout, how do I add a gallery view to it?

Comment: Why do you need separate gallery views? What exactly do you expect the final layout to look like...?

Comment: multiple gallery views, each for a separate album.. vertically stacked on top of each other..